# I can't find what I'm doing wrong when rendering a point light that is clipped by the floor

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I have a top down camera on my game, and I'm rendering a point light on my opengl fragment shader.

When the point light is far away from the floor it looks like I would expect it should look, like a perfect sphere of light.

[image]

But when the light is close to the floor is getting sliced not equally from the bottom but diagonally.

[image]

Is there something wrong with my implementation of the pointlight?

vertex

```
layout(location = 0) in vec2 v_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 v_light_position;

layout(location = 0) out vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) out vec2 light_position;

layout(binding = 0) uniform ubo {
    mat4 camera_view;
    vec3 light_color;
    float light_fade;
    float light_scatter;
    float light_intensity;
}

void main() {
    position = v_position;
    light_position = v_light_position;

    gl_Position = camera_view * vec4(position, 0., 1.);
}
```

fragment

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    float light_distance = distance(position, light_position.xy);

    float attenuation = 1 / (1. + light_fade * light_distance + light_scatter * (light_distance * light_distance));
    
    vec3 normal = texture(texture_1, uv).rgb;

    vec3 light_direction = normalize(
        vec3(light_position.x - position.x, position.y - light_position.y, light_position.z)
    );

    float ndotl = clamp(dot(normal, light_direction), 0., 1.);

    vec3 diffuse = vec3(light_intensity) * ndotl;

    color.rgb = light_color.rgb * diffuse * attenuation;
    color.a = 1.;
}
```

Getting the light clipped with the floor has sense, but the plane is perfectly flat with no slope, so it's awkward this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the problem was not in the code but in how I was creating my normals in Blender.

I was using a `vec3(.5, .5, 1.)` for a flat plane when it should have been `vec3(0., 0., 1.)`